# Ident of a 10 contact RJ45 style connector with 8 + 2 contacts

Tags: connector, rj45

I'm trying to find a plug that will fit into this RJ45 style socket.

The top picture shows 8 contacts just as you would expect from a RJ45 8P8C style socket, in fact you can plug a standard ethernet LAN cable into this socket and it mates perfectly.

The bottom picture is the same socket but it shows two extra contacts. These pins carry a voltage supply to an encoder.

I'm trying to source a compatible plug with 8+2 contacts but cannot find a reference to one anywhere so I was wondering if anyone recognises it as a standard part number?

Note that this **isn't** a [10P10C connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_connector#10P10C).

I can buy a pre-made cable with this plug on one end and a circular M23 on the other but I would like to source the plug to make up my own cable.

Matt.

[image: 8 contacts]
[image: 2 contacts]

Comment: Any part number or manufacturer logo on it?

Comment: Shielded RJ45 plug?

Comment: @Finbarr Unfortunately it hasn't.

Comment: @AlmostDone I've looked at shielded types but they are just shielded versions of the standard RJ45 8P8C type. I think the manufacturers plug that goes into the socket is shielded but with the addition of the extra 2 top contacts.

Comment: @Helixaxis Have you determined if these two pins terminate into the PCB ground or some other circuitry?

Comment: @AlmostDone I can confirm that across these 2 pins is a 10VDC supply that powers a SICK HIPERFACE encoder. So you could say that one pin goes to ground (But not necessarily the same ground as the control logic).

Answer (score 1):

The nearest plug I could find was the VW3M2208 from Schneider:
[https://www.schneider-electric.us/en/product/VW3M2208/encoder-connector-drive-end-rj45---set-of-5/](https://www.schneider-electric.us/en/product/VW3M2208/encoder-connector-drive-end-rj45---set-of-5)

Case closed.